# Why does the following code using IOmniThreadPool cause access violations?

Tags: delphi, threadpool, access-violation, omnithreadlibrary

In our Delphi XE4 application we are using an OmniThreadPool with MaxExecuting=4 to improve the efficiency of a certain calculation. Unfortunately we are having trouble with intermittent access violations (see for example the following MadExcept bug report http://ec2-72-44-42-247.compute-1.amazonaws.com/BugReport.txt). I was able to construct the following example which demonstrates the problem. After running the following console application, an access violation in System.SyncObjs.TCriticalSection.Acquire usually occurs within a minute or so. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong in the following code, or show me another way of achieving the desired result?

```
program OmniPoolCrashTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils,
  DSiWin32, GpLists,
  OtlSync, OtlThreadPool, OtlTaskControl, OtlComm, OtlTask;

const
  cTimeToWaitForException = 10 * 60 * 1000;  // program exits if no exception after 10 minutes
  MSG_CALLEE_FINISHED = 113; // our custom Omni message ID
  cMaxAllowedParallelCallees = 4; // enforced via thread pool
  cCalleeDuration = 10; // 10 miliseconds
  cCallerRepetitionInterval = 200; // 200 milliseconds
  cDefaultNumberOfCallers = 10; // 10 callers each issuing 1 call every 200 milliseconds

var
  gv_OmniThreadPool : IOmniThreadPool;

procedure OmniTaskProcedure_Callee(const task: IOmniTask);
begin
  Sleep(cCalleeDuration);
  task.Comm.Send(MSG_CALLEE_FINISHED);
end;

procedure PerformThreadPoolTest();
var
  OmniTaskControl : IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  OmniTaskControl := CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_Callee).Schedule(gv_OmniThreadPool);
  WaitForSingleObject(OmniTaskControl.Comm.NewMessageEvent, INFINITE);
end;

procedure OmniTaskProcedure_Caller(const task: IOmniTask);
begin
  while not task.Terminated do begin
    PerformThreadPoolTest();
    Sleep(cCallerRepetitionInterval);
  end;
end;

var
  CallerTasks : TGpInterfaceList<IOmniTaskControl>;
  i : integer;
begin
  gv_OmniThreadPool := CreateThreadPool('CalleeThreadPool');
  gv_OmniThreadPool.MaxExecuting := cMaxAllowedParallelCallees;
  CallerTasks := TGpInterfaceList<IOmniTaskControl>.Create();
  for i := 1 to StrToIntDef(ParamStr(1), cDefaultNumberOfCallers) do begin
    CallerTasks.Add( CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_Caller).Run() );
  end;
  Sleep(cTimeToWaitForException);
  for i := 0 to CallerTasks.Count-1 do begin
    CallerTasks[i].Terminate();
  end;
  CallerTasks.Free();
end.
```

Comment: This looks like the same question as the other one. You really should only ask one. I suggest that you delete one of them. Can you simplify this further. Ideally there should be a single .dpr file with no UI. A console app.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have now deleted the other question and also simplified the example code.

Comment: Excellent work. This really is a super SSCCE now. I'd upvote again if I was allowed to!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have here an example of hard-to-find [Task controller needs an owner](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/11/omnithreadlibrary-patterns-task.html) problem. What happens is that the task controller sometimes gets destroyed before the task itself and that causes the task to access memory containing random data.

Problematic scenario goes like this ([T] marks task, [C] marks task controller):

- [T] sends the message
- [C] receives the message and exits
- [C] is destroyed
- new task [T1] and controller [C1] are created
- [T] tries to exit; during that it accesses the shared memory area which was managed by [C] but was then destroyed and overwritten by the data belonging to [C1] or [T1]

In the Graymatter's workaround, `OnTerminated` creates an implicit owner for the task inside the OmniThreadLibrary which "solves" the problem.

The correct way to wait on the task to complete is to call taskControler.WaitFor.

```
procedure OmniTaskProcedure_Callee(const task: IOmniTask);
begin
  Sleep(cCalleeDuration);
end;

procedure PerformThreadPoolTest();
var
  OmniTaskControl : IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  OmniTaskControl := CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_Callee).Schedule(gv_OmniThreadPool);
  OmniTaskControl.WaitFor(INFINITE);
end;
```

I will look into replacing shared memory record with reference-counted solution which would prevent such problems (or at least make them easier to find).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response! Actually I think part of the reason I implemented this the way I did was because I wasn't sure what would happen if I called TOmniTaskControl.Comm.Receive after the task was already finished (in the original application MSG_CALLEE_FINISHED has data attached to it). But it seems that calling TOmniTaskControl.Comm.Receive after TOmniTaskControl.WaitFor is completely unproblematic after all :) I have now implemented it this way in our application. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Communication channel stays alive as long as the task controller is alive and messages are waiting for you to read them.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your termination message is causing the problem. Removing the message and the WaitForSingleObject stopped the AV. In my tests just adding a .OnTerminated(procedure begin end) before the .Schedule also did enough to change the flow and to stop the error. So the code in that case would look like this:

```
procedure PerformThreadPoolTest();
var
  OmniTaskControl : IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  OmniTaskControl := CreateTask(OmniTaskProcedure_Callee).OnTerminated(procedure begin end).Schedule(gv_OmniThreadPool);
  WaitForSingleObject(OmniTaskControl.Comm.NewMessageEvent, INFINITE);
end;
```

It looks to me like this might be the problem. otSharedInfo_ref has a property called MonitorLock. This is used to block changes to otSharedInfo_ref. If for some reason otSharedInfo_ref is freed while the acquire is waiting then you are likely to get some very weird behavior

The code as it stands looks like this:

```
procedure TOmniTask.InternalExecute(calledFromTerminate: boolean);
begin
  ...
    // with internal monitoring this will not be processed if the task controller owner is also shutting down
    sync := nil; // to remove the warning in the 'finally' clause below
    otSharedInfo_ref.MonitorLock.Acquire;
    try
      sync := otSharedInfo_ref.MonitorLock.SyncObj;
      if assigned(otSharedInfo_ref.Monitor) then
        otSharedInfo_ref.Monitor.Send(COmniTaskMsg_Terminated,
          integer(Int64Rec(UniqueID).Lo), integer(Int64Rec(UniqueID).Hi));
      otSharedInfo_ref := nil;
    finally sync.Release; end;
  ...
end; { TOmniTask.InternalExecute }
```

If otSharedInfo_ref.MonitorLock.Acquire is busy waiting and the object behind otSharedInfo_ref is freed then we end up in a very nasty place. Changing the code to this stopped the AV that was happening in InternalExecute:

```
procedure TOmniTask.InternalExecute(calledFromTerminate: boolean);
var
  ...
  monitorLock: TOmniCS;
  ...
begin
  ...
    // with internal monitoring this will not be processed if the task controller owner is also shutting down
    sync := nil; // to remove the warning in the 'finally' clause below
    monitorLock := otSharedInfo_ref.MonitorLock;
    monitorLock.Acquire;
    try
      sync := monitorLock.SyncObj;
      if assigned(otSharedInfo_ref) and assigned(otSharedInfo_ref.Monitor) then
        otSharedInfo_ref.Monitor.Send(COmniTaskMsg_Terminated,
          integer(Int64Rec(UniqueID).Lo), integer(Int64Rec(UniqueID).Hi));
      otSharedInfo_ref := nil;
    finally sync.Release; end;
  ...
end; { TOmniTask.InternalExecute }
```

I did start getting AV's in the OmniTaskProcedure_Callee method then on the "task.Comm.Send(MSG_CALLEE_FINISHED)" line so it's still not fixed but this should help others/Primoz to further identify what is going on. In the new error, task.Comm is often unassigned.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! Based on the testing I have done so far, your suggestion to add .OnTerminated(procedure begin end) seems to solve the problem in our application.